# Macbook Pro 13 Touchbar 2016 Should Be Reinstalled After Turned Off

Tags: macos

everyone. Please help.

My mac has this weird issue, I’ve been unable to start my mac after shutting it down. When I do, it would just show the apple logo, and the progress bar will only reach the middle and then turned off completely.

I did this almost 10 times just this morning, and decide to do my usual root so I can use my Mac again: by reinstalling the MacOS.

I’ve been doing this a couple of times for over 6 months, when I forgot that I should never shut down the laptop; “sleep” and “restart” work just fine.

Now I’m in the middle of reinstalling the MacOS, but I did “First Aid” in Disk Utility and found some error messages (Show in the images)

Does anybody have any idea what’s going on with my laptop and how to fix it. It’s so annoying to keep reinstalling MacOS anytime I forgot to charge the laptop.

Much thanks.
[image][image]

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :)  I hope you come to find this site has a lot to offer! In case you haven't already, it's worth taking the time to read the [tour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour). As for your question, did you mean to post some images? At present you seem to refer to some images, but there's no images in your post.